# Add one element to each element of existing arraylist in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to add one more element to existing array list, I have list of 10 records and I want to add one more element to each record. I am trying this code

```
var item = {};
item["ContentId"] = contentid;
response.push(item);
```

but this is adding a 11th record in list and what I want is to add my new attribute to each item of list.

How do I do that? Please help

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Thsi is your **18th** question. You really should be bothering to format by now. @Satpal: Frankly, if someone is just unwilling to do the work themselves, sometimes we should just leave it. Help a new user by all means, but...

Comment: This is also missing a lot of necessary information. What does your "arraylist" look like? (JavaScript doesn't have "arraylists".) `item` isn't an array, for instance. What are you starting with, what does the end result you want look like?

Comment: @Deepika What you just did is created an object ,updated one if its property and pushed it to the array assuming that response is an array

Comment: It is not an array list, it is an array sorry for using wrong term. 

I have array of 10 records and I want to add one more element to each array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Point noted.

Comment: I think you're going to need to add more information to this question. Show the "arrayList", show what result you're getting, and show what you would actually like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you confused record with element, element with property. 
In this exemple I add a property at each element of the array

```
var list = [{element1 : "Hello"}, {element1 : "bonjour"}, {element1 : "buenas dias"}];
var result = list.map((x) => x.element2 = "one more element");
console.log(list);

Run : 
[ { element1: 'Hello', element2: 'one more element' }, { element1: 'bonjour', element2: 'one more element' }, { element1: 'buenas dias', element2: 'one more element' } ]
```

Edit : Jquery is not needed for such an easy task